# Merging CSS Selectors or Not / Speed?

Tags: html, css, performance

I'm trying to work on first paint time, and looking into how effective the browser is at making sense of CSS.

In terms of file size, I'm not overly concerned which one is smaller, but what gets processed quicker? Merging Selectors, or keeping them separate here is an example:

Code A:

```
a { font-family: serif; font-size: 16px; background:#fff; }
p { font-family: serif; color: #333; background:#fff; }
h2 { font-family: arial; color: #333; font-size: 16px; background:#fff; }
```

Code B:

```
a, p, h2 { background:#fff; }
a, p { font-family: serif; }
a, h2 { font-size: 16px; }
p, h2 { color: #333; }
h2 { font-family: arial; }
```

Code C:
I could split everything into single css styles, and use HTML.

```
background-fff { background:#fff; }
family-serif { font-family: serif; }
size-16 { font-size: 16px; }
color-333 { color: #333; }

<a class="background-fff family-serif size-16 color-333"></a>
```

Technically, it's the exact same output, the second is obviously smaller, however, does the browser render it quicker and process it?

The reason I ask is that if I look at my entire sites CSS and do the second option for every single thing that has margin: 0; for example, the selector list separated by commas would be enormous.

This means, for a link  it would be pulling all the styles from various places. If I have 30 styles associated with a link the browser would be pulling each style from 30 different places in my sheet? so in my head, it seems this would be slower?

B is smaller, but is B processed quicker to process?

C seems a little silly.

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to profile your site.  There are probably 100 other things you could optimize first before tweaking these selectors.